# Opening directory from aquamacs emacs

Tags: emacs, directory, ls, cd, aquamacs

I am using the ^X d (dired) or (CTRL-X d) command to open a directory in Aquamacs emacs, however it will not open my Dropbox directory. Opening any other directory works fine. For example I would type (CTRL-x d) and then I get the prompt:

```
Dired (directory): ~/
```

I type:

`Dropbox`

Aquamacs tells me:

`Format Specifier doesn't match argument type`

My main goal here is to be able to navigate directories and files like I do in the terminal. Which does not seem possible without being able to open my Dropbox directory.

1. How can I open my Dropbox directory inside Aquamacs using the Dired command?

Answer (score 0):

> navigate directories and files like I do in the terminal

So in a terminal, you can `cd Dropbox` from anywhere and it works?

What if you typed `~/Dropbox` from <kbd>C-x d</kbd> prompt?

Comment: If I do cd Dropbox in the terminal it works (given that I am at the home directory) The prompt given by Aquamacs emacs is prefaced with ~/ as noted above.

Comment: This works for me on plain old Gnu Emacs.  I don't have Aquamacs.  Perhaps you can try with another Emacs at least to get a firmer handle on the issue.

Comment: I just ran emacs through the terminal and it works for me there too.